# Not able to install pyaudio python module

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyaudio

I can't install Pyaudio in my python 3.10.1. using `pip install pipwin` then `pipwin install pyaudio`.

Error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools>pipwin install pyaudio
Package `pyaudio` found in cache
Downloading package . . .
https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/y2rycu7g/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pipwin.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pipwin\command.py", line 103, in main
    cache.install(package)
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 300, in install
    wheel_file = self.download(requirement)
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 294, in download
    return self._download(requirement, dest)
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 290, in _download
    obj.start()
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pySmartDL\pySmartDL.py", line 267, in start
    urlObj = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=self.timeout, context=self.context)
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ayamk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Does it work with a different version of python? The [homepage](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) says that "there are wheels compatible with the official distributions of Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6"

Comment: @Battleman `pipwin` installs from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

the `.whl` for pyaudio is not available at the [URL](https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/y2rycu7g/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl) pipwin is trying to download it from

Try doing `pipwin refresh` before doing the installation

[see this github issue](https://github.com/lepisma/pipwin/issues/49)

Alternatively,
You can download the `.whl` directly from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
and do

`pip install <path-to-downloaded-whl>`